# Multiple relations to the same model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have two models, Classes and People. A Class might have one or two People as instructors, and twenty people as students. So, I need to have multiple relationships between the models -- one where it's 1->M for instructors, and one where it's 1->M for students.

Edit: Instructors and Students *must* be the same; instructors could be students in other classes, and vice versa.

I'm sure this is quite easy, but Google isn't pulling up anything relevant and I'm just not finding it in my books.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are many options here, but assuming instructors are always instructors and students are always students, you can use inheritance:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base; end  # btw, model names are singular in rails
class Student < Person; end
class Instructor < Person; end
```

then

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base  # renamed here because class Class already exists in ruby
  has_many :students
  has_many :instructors
end
```

Just remember that for single table inheritance to work, you need a `type` column in the `people` table.

#### using an association model might solve your issue

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :studentships
  has_many :instructorships
  has_many :students,    :through => :studentships
  has_many :instructors, :through => :instructorships
end

class Studentship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :student, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "student_id"
end

class Instructorship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :instructor, :class_name => "Person", :foreign_key => "instructor_id"
end
```

Comment: Hey, that's pretty clever, but unfortunately, someone could be both an instructor and a student, so I don't think this will work as-is.

Comment: haha, this was a long time ago but shouldn't the relationships be has_many :through going both "directions"? A Person should be able to teach more than one course?

Answer (score 8):

in my case i have Asset and User model 
Asset can be create by an user and could be assigned to a user
and User can create many assets and can have many Asset
solution of my problem  was 
    asset.rb

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :creator ,:class_name=>'User'
belongs_to :assigned_to, :class_name=>'User' 

end
```

and

```
user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :created_assets, :foreign_key => 'creator_id', :class_name => 'Asset'
has_many :assigned_assets , :foreign_key => 'assigned_to_id', :class_name => 'Asset'

end
```

so your solution could be

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :students ,:foreign_key => 'student_id', :class_name => 'Person'
has_many  :teachers, :foreign_key => 'teacher_id', :class_name => 'Person'

end
```

and

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to  :course_enrolled,:class_name=>'Course'
belongs_to  :course_instructor,:class_name=>'Course'

end
```

Comment: Doesn't this restrict the Person to having at most one course_enrolled and one course_instructor? I think to fully set it up they have to be has_many :through associations.